# Как пользоваться Gitlab на Debian 8?

Tags: debian, gitlab

Установил себе на сервер Gitlab. Все стало без проблем, но проблема в том, что я не знаю, как его открыть. Куда мне смотреть, что бы я мог увидеть веб страничку с установленным Gitlab?

Comment: Как установили-то?

Comment: https://about.gitlab.com/2015/05/01/gitlab-on-debian-8/. Что никто не ставил себе?